# How to code a script to go to the next scene after winning a round

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, scene

How to code a script to go to the next scene after winning a round?
what to do to move to the next scene when the player wins the round and not when the mouse button is pressed.  I am mainly referring to this passage
This is my code for scene switching:

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator transition;

    public float transitionTime = 1f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtDown(0))
        {
            LoadNextLevel();
        }
    }

    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadLevel(int levelIndex)
    {
        transition.SetTrigger("Start");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);

        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelIndex);
    }

}
```

And this is my code that controls the whole game:

```html
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


[RequireComponent(typeof(GameUI))]
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{

 
    public static GameController Instance { get; private set; }

    [SerializeField]
    private int knifeCount;

    [Header("Knife Spawning")]
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector2 knifeSpawnPosition;
    [SerializeField]
    
    private GameObject knifeObject;

    
    public GameUI GameUI { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {
        
        Instance = this;

        GameUI = GetComponent<GameUI>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        
        GameUI.SetInitialDisplayedKnifeCount(knifeCount);
        
        SpawnKnife();
    }

    
    public void OnSuccessfulKnifeHit()
    {
        if (knifeCount > 0)
        {
            SpawnKnife();
        }
        else
        {
            StartGameOverSequence(true);
        }
    }

    
    private void SpawnKnife()
    {
        knifeCount--;
        Instantiate(knifeObject, knifeSpawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }

   
    public void StartGameOverSequence(bool win)
    {
        StartCoroutine("GameOverSequenceCoroutine", win);
    }

    
    private IEnumerator GameOverSequenceCoroutine(bool win)
    {
        if (win)
        {
            
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.3f);
            
        }
        else
        {
            GameUI.ShowRestartButton();
        }
    }

    public void RestartGame()
    {
        
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

Comment: After clicking play, trigger the function to jump to the next scene.
If it is a built-in GUI, when setting this button, it can be triggered in the function

Comment: Define two methods "Scene1()" and "Scene2()" to use SceneManager.LoadScene("scene name") or SceneManager.LoadScene(subscript) to switch scenes.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is call LoadNextLevel() when conditions are met to load next level.
I think you need to call it here:

```
if (win)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.3f);
        LoadNextLevel();
    }
```

Comment: I don't know exactly how to trigger it

Comment: In GameOverSequenceCoroutine inside if(win) call LoadNextLevel(); just like the code I show above, if it is not working then maybe you have a bug in your code.

Comment: when I do this, I get such a mistake error CS0103: The name 'LoadNextLevel' does not exist in the current context

Comment: well i see what is the problem, use FindObjectOfType<LevelLoader>.LoadNextLevel();
or make that function static or create a field in GameController and drag and drop LevelLoader to that field in inspector.... these stuff are basics.

Comment: do you mean it?                                                                                                                 
 FindObjectOfType<LevelLoader>.LoadNextLevel();      {
        if (win)
        {
            
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.3f);
            LoadNextLevel();
        }
        else
        {
            GameUI.ShowRestartButton();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
  {
    if (PlayerControl.showflag == 1) ;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
  }
The following is to press the E key to switch the scene
        void Update()
    {
      if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
       {
           SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex+1);
    } 
}
```

Can the above code be implemented, I hope so?